# I need help creating a Navigation Bar? Hover over links for a large div box to appear?

Tags: css, html, hover, navigationbar

```
`<ul id="main-nav">
<li>
    <a href="#">Menu item</a>
    <div class="sub-nav">
        <p>Anything</p>
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#">Menu item</a>
    <div class="sub-nav" style="left: -80px;">
        <p>Anything</p>
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#">Menu item</a>
    <div class="sub-nav" style="left: -160px;">
        <p>Anything</p>
   </div>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#">Menu item</a>
    <div class="sub-nav" style="left: -240px;">
        <p>Anything</p>
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#">Menu item</a>
    <div class="sub-nav" style="left: -320px;">
        <p>Anything</p>
    </div>
</li>
```

`

I want to be able to put content into the div (Links, Images, Text, etc). I am trying to make the div box the same size as the navigation bar its self specifically 1050px in width (I want the navigation bar and div box to be 1050px in width). When a user hovers over a link in the navigation bar I want the div box to appear with all its content inside.

this is something like it: http://jsfiddle.net/ELyQW/2/ ~ (But if you look closely you can see the box moves on every new link which I do not want to happen.)

Look at the navigation bar on this website for similar reference. [pacsun](http://www.pacsun.com/).

Thank You SO much for your help!

And if you do help me create a new bar I strongly recommend you do not use the jsfiddle I posted, but if you have to go for it! 
Thank you once again!

Comment: What would have made sense to me is to set `position: relative;` on `#main-nav` rather then the `<li>` elements... but the issue still persists. Funny coincidence, I'm trying to work out the same issue for a client's website and I've been looking at ways to get around that problem, nothing that actually helped thus far.

Comment: is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/harsh_shah/ELyQW/27/) sumthin you are loking for>

Comment: @adamj What I actually did was change the style="left: -160px;" of each <li> (<div class="sub-nav" style="left: -80px;">) it worked perfectly until I opened my website on a different browser like Internet Explorer. I realized the margin left was not exact anymore... But I mean you should give it a try to see if this problem happens to you. It might just work for you.

Comment: @user3308895 Hehe great minds think alike. Came to the same conclusion while playing around with your jsFiddle, was just about to suggest the same. Though that would suck since you would have to have fixed width #main-menu elements :(

Comment: @HarshShah If you look closely the issue is still there, the sub menus still drift like 2 or 3 pixels to the right when you hover over any elements apart from the first one.

Comment: @HarshShah What I am really seeking to find is a new navigation bar that is similar to [macys](http://www.macys.com/) [eonline](http://www.eonline.com/) [pacsun](www.pacsun.com) Something like their navigation bars. Where I can put content inside the hover div.

Comment: @user3308895 Ah yep. Most of them just have a second nav of sorts that contain all the sub menus. Would be awesome if there was a way to just keep it all contained within the #main-menu without having that div skip thing happening.

Comment: [is this](http://jsfiddle.net/harsh_shah/ELyQW/30/) Ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yay success!

http://jsfiddle.net/hjZz9/1/

```
<div id="main-menu-container">
    <ul id="main-menu">
        <li>
            <a href="#">Main menu</a>
            <div class="sub-menu">
                Testing 123
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Main menu</a>
            <div class="sub-menu">
                Testing 123
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Main menu</a>
            <div class="sub-menu">
                Testing 123
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Main menu</a>
            <div class="sub-menu">
                Testing 123
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

#main-menu-container {
    position: relative;
}
#main-menu {
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
#main-menu li {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 15px;
}
#main-menu li:hover .sub-menu {
    display: block;
}
.sub-menu {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
        left: 0; right: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

**Edit:** I've added `right: 0;` to `.sub-menu` just so it stretches from end to end, you can change this to your own preference of course.

Comment: @user3308895 Most welcome. 2 birds one stone, finally I can finish the stuff for my client as well woohoo!

Answer (score 0):

You could try position fixed instead of absolute. Then left position both the div and ul correctly and you will achieve it. Here is a [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/ELyQW/29/)

```
.sub-nav {display: none; position: fixed; left: 40px; width: 400px; z-index: 999; background: #f2f2f2;}
```